# DtsDebugHost crashes after upgrade to SQL Server 2012 SP2

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

We have an SSIS package developed in VS 2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1) running against SQL Server 2012.

Since we've upgraded to SQL Server 2012 SP2 (11.0.5058) one of the previously working packages is failing.

When running in SQL Server Agent, we get the following error:

*The step did not generate any output.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.*

When running in BIDS (VS 2010), we get the following crash:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>   Runtime Error!
>   Program: C:\Progr...
>   R6025
>   - pure virtual function call

In the Event Log, the following appears:

> Faulting application name: DtsDebugHost.exe, version: 2011.110.5058.0, time stamp: 0x537422a5
>   Faulting module name: MSVCR100.dll, version: 10.0.40219.325, time stamp: 0x4df2bcac
>   Exception code: 0x40000015
>   Fault offset: 0x00000000000761c9
>   Faulting process id: 0x10da0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cfcbb6ddbc218e
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\binn\DtsDebugHost.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll
>   Report Id: 28659fee-37aa-11e4-8361-50e549e06c22

Has anyone experienced this and is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up contacting Microsoft technical support. Here is the solution: install CU2 for SQL Server 2012 SP2:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2983175/en-us